# CONCAT with Laravel eloquent between two fields from table field

Tags: database, laravel, postgresql, concatenation

I want to CONCAT two fields from different tables using Laravel elequent. My schema is like this

```
customers:
id
name
number

customer_types:
type
description
taxable_price
```

Every customer has a customer_type. I want to CONCAT CUSTOMER.NAME CUSTOMER_TYPES.TYPE as customer_plus_type:

```
Desire Output:

    {
      "name": CUSTOMER_NAME,
      "customer_plus_type": CUSTOMER_NAME - TYPEs,
      "customer_type": {
         "customer_plus_type": CUSTOMER_NAME - TYPEs
       }
    }
```

I have already tried this with my unlucky day.

```
$customers = Customer::with(['customerType'=> function($q) {
            $q->select(['id',
                DB::raw("CONCAT(custmers.name,' - ',customer_types.type)  AS customer_plus_type")
            ]);
    }])->first();

    return $customers;
```

So, how can I CONCAT customers.name and customer_types.type as customer_plus_type?
Thanks much!

Comment: Do you need a solution with `concat` in the database or is a solution within your PHP code acceptable?

Comment: Anyway, there is a typo in the table name of `customers.name`.

Comment: I have to do it using CONCAT. So what things need to do? I can do within same table field but what’s for the relation ‘with’ tables.

Comment: Please be more clear on what's going on. You posted a bunch of code but didn't explained what happened. Any error messages? The concatenation not work? The field don't appear? If you don't explain this, becomes hard to help you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll have to join the tables yourself. Using `with('other_table')` does only eager load the related models, but not within one query. Each referenced model passed to `with()` will result in an additional query.

In your case, a solution could look like this:

```
$customer = Customer::query()
    ->join('customer_types', 'customers.customer_type_id', '=', 'customer_types.id')
    ->select([
        'customers.*',
        DB::raw("CONCAT(customers.name, ' - ', customer_types.type) as customer_plus_type"),
    ])
    ->first();
```

This will select all fields of the `customers` table as well as your custom field with the name `customer_plus_type`. Please make sure you change the `customers.customer_type_id` field in the `join` accordingly. From your question it is unclear how it was named.

By the way, if you still need to eager load the `customerType` relation, you can just add `with('customerType')` somewhere before the call to `first()`.